# is it possible to programmatically determine what object a method is being delegated to in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a set of objects, some of which have an organization_id attribute, and others of which delegate organization_id.

for example:

```
class Department
  belongs_to :organization
end
class Program
  belongs_to :department
  delegate :organization_id, to: :department
end

class Role
  belongs_to :organization
end
class UsersRole
  belongs_to :role
  delegate :organization_id, to: :role
end
```

i would like a means by which to programmatically determine which class of object the organization_id is being delegated to so that i could do something like the following

```
def find_organization_id_source(object)
   object.organization_id.method_im_hoping_exists
end
$ find_organization_id_source(@program)
>> Department
$ find_organization_id_source(@users_role)
>> Role
```

Comment: try `object.method(:organization_id).owner` ,,, ?

Comment: good idea, but it doesn't seem to work. for example program.method(:organization_id).owner returns Program.

Comment: This is metaprogarmming to create new methods. so not possible https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/97fc7bf76ca9dbfdaeee5533eb5125d182e8923b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L181

Comment: The whole point of delegate is that the objects behave the same. So if you want to do distinguish the objects, you probably should use another design pattern.

Comment: well, most of the time i do want them to behave the same, but i have one method i just realized would be helpful to make, and in that method i want to build the associations, but i can't associate the object directly to the organization, if it has no such attribute, so i thought if i could tell what object class it's delegating organization to, i could work it out that way. not sure what pattern would work better in this case, or if i just need to find a different way of accomplishing what i'm trying to do.

Comment: I'll defer to @wand-maker if they say that it can't be done.  But... isn't it possible that `binding.receiver` would be of use here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible.  As can be seen in source of [`active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb),  Rails creates a new method that will internally invoke the delegated method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_delegated?(object, delegated_attribute)
  object.attributes.include? delegated_attribute
end
```

It won't tell you where you're getting the value from but it should tell you if you've gotten it through delegation.

Comment: it's a good start, but ultimately, if i can't tell precisely which class of object it's being delegated to then it doesn't do what i need.